# Why should lists start from 0 instead of 1?

Tags: arrays, list

I don't feel there are very good reasons for having lists and arrays to start from index 0.
I think is more natural to have them starting from 1 as in `L[1],...,L[length(L)]`.
There are languages that use 1 instead of 0, such as Matlab, but they are scarce.

Anyone has reasons for starting index in lists from zero?

PD: I already read the Dijkstra arguments and the pointer arguments in C that talk about memory offset with pointers. I don't find them very convincing.

Comment: This does not look constructive. You don't seem to be _asking a question_ so much as looking for an opportunity to try to convince respondents that they are wrong and you are right.

Comment: See [Why are zero-based arrays the norm?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm)

Comment: @HenningMakholm that's subjective. IMO language design choices ARE constructive, as they might provide some valuable insight.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Except it does not fit the format for SO; nor is there any definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

In early days of programming  most of thing where memory oriented and programmer had to suffer a lot with addresses.Introducing 1 based index could have created another havoc(calculation overhead) for address calculation for the programs dealing with the system programming.It was one very good reason to keep arrays and pointers as analogous representation of each other .

Answer (score 0):

It might be a fair observation that using 0 based indexing for post array collections is not per se necessary, but having two indexing systems is a nuisance (I'm thinking VB6 collections vs arrays) further more using a single indexing system facilitates treating both primitive and complex collection types consistently (or even generically depending on the language in question). So given that there is, at best, no benefit to selectively using 1 and 0 based indexing depending on the type, and there is, at least, some benefit to using 0 based indexing I would guess that is why it has persisted.